# How to setup HTTPS on qbittorrent WebUI with letsencrypt/certbot?

Tags: command-line, encryption, bittorrent, https, qbittorrent

I am running `qbittorrent-nox` on an Ubuntu server (16.04).

I use a dynamic DNS address to access the WebUI.

In the github page there is a tutorial to setup HTTPS, but only using self-signed certs.

I have already tried using `certbot` with the `--webroot` and `--standalone` options, but to no avail. One of the main issues is that I can't figure out where the files for the webUI are actually being served from, otherwise `--webroot` should work.

Can someone please explain how I can make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this on Archlinux but I think it would be the same on Ubuntu.

### Certificate request

Run certbot like this:

```
sudo certbot certonly --manual -d yourhostname.org
```

Follow the instructions. At some point certbot will tell you to run a web server to verify you own the hostname. It will also provide a couple of commands to run a simple web server with python. Run these commands as root in a new shell on your server.

Be sure to forward port `80` from your router to the server hosting `qbittorrent-nox` and to open the same port on your server firewall. If using `ufw`, this is the command you want:

```
sudo ufw allow WWW
```

`WWW` is a simple configuration to allow connections on port 80.

When the verification procedure is finished, you will find key and certificate files in `/etc/letsencrypt/live/yourhostname.org`. Copy/paste `privkey.pem` and `cert.pem` in your `qbittorrent-nox` web-ui and you are done.

PS. At the end of this you can kill the python webserver.

PPS. If you are not using port `80` on your server you can also remove it from `ufw ALLOW` rules and from the port forwarding of your router.

### Certificate automatic renewal

Basically you need to automate the steps presented in the previous section.

The command to execute is this:

```
certbot renew
 --manual-auth-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/auth-hook.sh \        
 --manual-cleanup-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/cleanup-hook.sh \            
 --post-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/post-hook.sh
```

The `hooks` are basically scripts executed by certbot. certbot will export some environment variables to the scripts. Please refer to [certbot docs](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#pre-and-post-validation-hooks) for more details.

Scripts are placed in `/etc/letsencrypt/scripts`. Create this folder and place your scripts there or use any other folder of your choice.

#### Scripts explanation and code:

`auth-hook.sh` is executed before the verification procedure. It sets up a simple web server to expose the CERTBOT_TOKEN.

```
#!/bin/zsh                                                                  

ufw allow WWW                                                                 

mkdir -p /tmp/certbot/public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge                  
cd /tmp/certbot/public_html                                                   
printf "%s" $CERTBOT_VALIDATION > .well-known/acme-challenge/$CERTBOT_TOKEN 

$(command -v python2 || command -v python2.7 || command -v python2.6) -c "import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer; s = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('', 80), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler);  s.serve_forever()" &> /dev/null &
```

`cleanup-hook.sh` will be executed after the verification procedure no matter if the certificate has been renewed or not. We use it to cleanup the web server.

```
#!/bin/zsh                                                                  

kill $(ps aux | grep SimpleHTTPServer | awk 'NR==1{print $2}')                

rm -rf /tmp/certbot/public_html/.well-known/acme-challenge                    

ufw delete allow WWW
```

`post-hook.sh` will be executed when the certificate is actually renewed. We use it to update `/home/user/.config/qBittorrent/qBittorrent.conf`.

```
#!/bin/zsh

systemctl stop qbittorrent.service &&

/etc/letsencrypt/scripts/update_config.py \
 --hostname $CERTBOT_DOMAIN \
 --configfile /home/user/.config/qBittorrent/qBittorrent.conf &&

systemctl start qbittorrent.service &&
```

**Please note**: `qbittorrent` configuration is placed in the home folder of the user running it; edit this script accordingly to your configuration.

`update_config.py` updates the `qBittorrent.conf`. I used python because the ConfigParser module was very convenient to edit INI files (`key=value`). Someone smarter than me can probably achieve the same with `sed` or `awk`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3                                                          

import argparse                                                               
import configparser                                                           
Config = configparser.ConfigParser()                                          
Config.optionxform = str                                                      

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Updates qbittorrent config.') 
parser.add_argument('--hostname', required=True)                              
parser.add_argument('--configfile', required=True)                            
args = parser.parse_args()                                                    

with open('/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + args.hostname + '/cert.pem', 'r') as f: 
    cert = f.read()                                                           
with open('/etc/letsencrypt/live/' + args.hostname + '/privkey.pem', 'r') as f:
    key = f.read()                                                          

cert = cert.replace('\n', '\\n')[:-2]                                         
cert = "\"@ByteArray(" + cert + ")\""                                         
key = key.replace('\n', '\\n')[:-2]                                           
key = "@ByteArray(" + key + ")"                                               

Config.read(args.configfile)                                                  
Config["Preferences"]["WebUI\HTTPS\Certificate"] = cert                       
Config["Preferences"]["WebUI\HTTPS\Key"] = key                                
with open(args.configfile, 'w') as f:                                         
    Config.write(f, space_around_delimiters=False)
```

#### Dry run

Edit these scripts at your needs. Now try to run the previous command with `--dry-run` option. This will run the renewal procedure even if the certificate has not expired.

```
certbot renew --manual-auth-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/auth-hook.sh --manual-cleanup-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/cleanup-hook.sh --post-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/post-hook.sh --dry-run
```

#### Cron Job

If everything is fine, you can setup a cron job.

```
# EDITOR=vim crontab -e

00 04,16 * * * sleep $((RANDOM % 60)); certbot renew --quiet --manual-auth-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/auth-hook.sh --manual-cleanup-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/cleanup-hook.sh --post-hook /etc/letsencrypt/scripts/post-hook.sh
```

The job will run every day at 04:00 and 16:00. The random sleep will select a random minute within the selected hours (as suggested by [certbot docs](https://certbot.eff.org/#arch-other)).

We add `--quiet` option: it is better for cron jobs.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked. One final question: does the auto-renewal work? Do I need the python webserver on port 80 for it to work?

Comment: Probably. The verification system should be the same, but I have not tried the renewal. I'll do it when I have time and I'll let you know.

Comment: Ok, I will wait for your results then. Meanwhile everything seems to be working fine, so I am going to accept your answer. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Frank I updated my answer with scripts and information to setup the automatic renewal. The scripts will also update `qbittorrent` configuration. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ok, have you tested the automatic renewal yourself? This whole post would be a great addition to qBittorrent's wiki on Github, if you have the time to contact the maintainers. Great job!

Comment: @Frank Today I fixed a couple of bugs in the python script. I also added stop/reload of the service when configuration file changes. Of course I tested all of this. I'll contact maintainers as soon as possible.